# Program Doesnt Print the Correct CSV Output

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm using Django to develop a web app for users to upload 2 different csv files, then the web app finds those differences, mark the differences respectively, and then print it as an output. When I run the code, it doesnt give me the correct output. Here is **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import difflib
import datetime
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import FileResponse
from .forms import FileForm
from .forms import UploadFileForm

def handle_uploaded_file(file1,file2): # handle_uploaded_file is a function that takes 2 files uploaded by the users
    fileone = file1.readlines() # define fileone and read lines from 1st file
    filetwo = file2.readlines() # define filetwo and read lines from 2nd file
    fileone =[line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in fileone]
    filetwo =[line.decode("utf-8").strip() for line in filetwo]

    csv_old = csv.reader(fileone, delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    header = next(csv_old)
    old_data = {}
    for row in csv_old:
        old_data[count] = row
        count += 1

    csv_new = csv.reader(filetwo, delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    header = next(csv_new)
    new_data = {}
    for row in csv_new:
        new_data[count] = row
        count += 1

    set_new_data = set(new_data)
    set_old_data = set(old_data)

    added = [['Added'] + new_data[v] for v in set_new_data - set_old_data]
    deleted = [['Deleted'] + old_data[v] for v in set_old_data - set_new_data]
    in_both = set_old_data & set_new_data
    changed = [['Changed'] + new_data[v] for v in in_both if old_data[v] != new_data[v]]

    with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=',')
        csv_output.writerow(['History'] + header)
        csv_output.writerows(sorted(added + deleted + changed, key=lambda x: x[1:]))

def index(request): # index is a function for the upload button
    if request.method == 'POST': # POST method inserts something to the server
        print(request.FILES)
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("cool")
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.get('file1'),request.FILES.get('file2'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('results/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'form': form})

def results(request): # results is a function that sends difference.csv back to the user once the file is ready
    file_path = (r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\PycharmProjects\filecomparison\results.csv') #  adding an absolute path in the server, pinpoints that exact file, very important, r is to produce raw string and handle unicodeescape error
    response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'))
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv' # the type of the file that will be send is .txt/.csv
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=results.csv' # produces an attachment file for users to download called with difference in .csv file
    return response
```

Here is **sample1.csv**

```
Planet  Account ID  First Name  Last Name   Premise Station City
Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
Nebula  1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
Neptune 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
```

Here is **sample2.csv**

```
Planet  Account ID  First Name  Last Name   Premise Station City
Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Montgomery
Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Minneapolis
Neptune 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
Mercury 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Eden Gate
```

*STATION SHOULD HAVE 0 INFORMATION(0 ROWS), its there just for testing purposes

Here is **output.csv** that I get

```
History Planet  Account ID  First Name  Last Name   Premise Station City
Changed Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Minneapolis
Changed Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Montgomery
Changed Mercury 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Eden Gate
Changed Neptune 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
```

Here is the **expected** output

```
History Planet  Account ID  First Name  Last Name   Premise Type    Station City
Changed Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Montgomery
Changed Earth   1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Minneapolis
Deleted Nebula  1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Phoenix
Added   Mercury 1234    Pete    Montgomery  Unknown     Eden Gate
```

. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the output of `added + deleted + changed` before writing to the excel? You can put a print statement just before the `with open('results.csv'...` clause. This will help you figure out where the code went wrong.

Comment: yes I put print(changed) then change it into print(added) right above open clause like you told me, it prints the same thing and now I figure out why is that, if you could take a look at the edited question, and help me out, i'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
   csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=',') #this line is moved up 
   csv_output.writerow(['History'] + header)
   csv_output.writerows(sorted(added + deleted + changed, key=lambda x: x[0:]))
```

Comment: No, when I changed to that, I get 3 same results (. . . Pete Montgomery . . . Keywood times 3)

Comment: I solved the issue but there is another issue that comes up, I edited the question, if you could take a look at it again, thanks